# Solving a Recurrence Relationship T(n) = T(n-√n)+1

Tags: algorithm, asymptotic-complexity, divide-and-conquer

I am learning the divide and conquer algorithm in Coursera, I have encountered this recurrence relationship:

`T(n) = T(n-√n)+1`

The answer given is:

`O(√n)`

I have learnt master method and recurrence tree analysis but I don't know how to analyze this recurrence relationship.
Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2):

[image]

We can obtain the upper bound at this stage by using a binomial expansion:

[image]

Note that the RHS is smaller than the LHS for large `n`, meaning that each time we apply the approximation we are subtracting a smaller value from the parameter to `T`, and thus the result will be an upper bound.

Continuing to `m` iterations:

[image]

Assuming that `T(n)` terminates at `n = 0` (or some constant, doesn't matter)

[image]

And therefore the complexity is `O(m) = O(√n)`.

---

EDIT: the `= 4√n` above was wrong, sorry - should have been `(2+5/√2)√n`